# Save filenames to textfile and add a string in front of line

Tags: batch-file, cmd, text-files, filenames, dir

I would like to save the output of a list of files to a file (by using a Windows batch file). I know I can do this by the command `dir /b *.* > start.txt`, but for each line in the file "start.txt" I would like to add **@@** in front of the file name. So the contents of start.txt should be:

```
@@filename1  
@@filename2
...
```

I know by using the command `Echo` I can add text. But how can I do this for each line that is written to the file?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `for` parser on the output of `dir`:

```
(for /f "usebackq" %%l in (`dir /b \`) do echo @@%%l) > start.txt
```

Note the `%%` escaping - this is required when running inside a .bat/.cmd, which you presumably are.